# Apex variables with HighCharts.js

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have some methods in a controller that returns a Decimal, and display in a HighCharts.js line graph as the method is called in a data series.

A method is:

```
public static String getNewBusinessClosedWonJanuary() {
    List<AggregateResult> oppItems = [SELECT SUM(Amount)amt FROM Opportunity WHERE Billing_Effective_Date__c = THIS_YEAR AND Once_off_fee__c = false AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Effective_Date__c) = 1 AND RecordTypeId =:oppNBRecordTypeIdClosedWon AND StageName =: stages];
    Decimal[] lstInt=new Decimal[]{};
    Decimal amountX;
        for(AggregateResult ar: oppItems){
        amountX=Integer.valueOf(ar.get('amt'));  
             if(amountX == null) {
             amountX = 0;  
            }
        lstInt.add(amountX);
    }
return JSON.serialize(lstInt); 
}
```

And the setter in the VF page is:

```
   series: [{
        name: 'New Business - YTD',
        data: [{!NewBusinessClosedWonJanuary}]
```

I now want to pass in an expression that takes the sum of both NewBusinessClosedWonJanuary and NewBusinessClosedWonFebruary. I have tried to do this via  declarations, such as:

```
<apex:variable var="janNB" value="{!NewBusinessClosedWonJanuary}"></apex:variable>
<apex:variable var="febNB" value="{!NewBusinessClosedWonJanuary + NewBusinessClosedWonFebruary}"></apex:variable>
```

However, when I try to reference this in the data series, the page fails to load:

```
data: [{!janNB}, {!janNB + febNB}]
```

How can I simply add the results of two methods and set the result in the VF page?

Comment: Easiest way, create a method in your controller to add them and assigned to a property that the page can access. You could also try this: `<apex:variable var="febNB" value="{!janNB + NewBusinessClosedWonFebruary}">`

Comment: Thanks Eric. I have tried the latter and it didn't work.    <apex:variable var="janNB" value="{!NewBusinessClosedWonJanuary}"></apex:variable>
    <apex:variable var="febNB" value="{!NewBusinessClosedWonFebruary}"></apex:variable> data: [{!janNB + febNB}]